# Primefaces wizard move to the next tab on an event

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a prime faces wizard and a dataTable, my page successfully go to the next wizard tab if I selected an item from the dataTable, but my problem is when inserting a new data to the dataTable I want the wizard to go to the next tab if the insert was successful, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the client side API from backing bean, after the insert was successful.

Add a widgetVar to your wizard

```
<p:wizard widgetVar="wiz" ...>
     ...
<p/wizard>
```

Add the client execute, after the data is successfully inserted.

```
public void insertData() {
    // Insert data
    if (successfully) {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.execute("PF('wiz').next()");
    }
}
```